# How can I make an ASP control render with single quotes rather than double quotes?

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have a WebForms button:

```
<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Hello"/>
```

That I need to be rendered on the client with single quotes so as to fit in with a framework I'm using such as:

```
<input type='submit" name='ctl08$mapControl$repTestiminialScripts$ctl01$ctl00' value='Hello' />
```

**Is there a way to make it so when rendered, the ASP button will have single quotes rather than double quotes around the property?**

Comment: Which version of asp.net are you using?

Comment: We're using version > 4.5

Comment: Which property to render as single quote? By the way in HTML single quote & double quotes usage for attribute value are insignificant, single quotes just mandatory if you're using server-side binding like `<%# Eval(...) %>` or `<%# Bind(...) %>`.

Comment: All of them, like in my example. The rendered server control is rendered into a string property in some JavaScript, because of the quotes in the rendered server control it escapes out of the JavaScript string.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to get around the issue I was having by using a [JavaScript Template Literal](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

```
javascriptObject.metadata = {
                description: `<asp:Button runat="server" Text="Hello"/>`
            };
```

This then allowed the server control to render without escaping out of the string.